# GoogleMaps.onCameraIdle Listener should fire after waiting a while

Tags: android, google-maps, listener, google-maps-android-api-2, android-handler

I have a Google Map and load markers from a backend in current GeoBox. I want to wait a while before CameraIdle load the markers.

User:
Swipe or Zoom -> Wait for another gesture -> OnCameraIdle()

```
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    showProgressBar();
    loadMarkers();
    hideProgressBar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:
Create a Handler and Runnable.

```
Handler loadHandler = new Handler();
Runnable loadRUnnable = new Runnable(){...};
@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i) {
    if(loadHandler != null){
        loadHandler.removeCallbacks(loadRunnable);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    if(loadHandler != null){
        loadHandler.removeCallbacks(loadRunnable);
        loadHandler.postDelayed(loadRunnable, 1000);
    }
}
```